# On selecting the radio button how to get the text of the selected radio button where the text is in the next column

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

On selecting the radio button how to get the text of the selected radio button where the text is in the next column

I randomly select the radio button and then i need to Store the selected Radio button's Vessel Name

Below is the Code:

```java
public   String checkselectedplanningVesselname()
    {
        String rowOne = "";
            
            List<WebElement> radiobuttonoptions =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'mat-table cdk-table')]//following::mat-radio-button[contains(@id,'mat-radio')]"));
             for (int i=0;i<radiobuttonoptions.size();i++)
            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'mat-table cdk-table')]//following::mat-radio-button[contains(@id,'mat-radio')]")).isSelected())
            {
             
            
             rowOne = radiobuttonoptions.get(i).getText(); = 
             System.out.println("Print the Selected VesselName:"+ rowOne);
           break;
         
        }
        return rowOne;
    }
```

Below is the HTML of the table :

HTML:

```html
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
       <tr _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted">
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted">
             <span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                <!---->
                <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-epp-c110="" color="primary" class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" id="mat-radio-1"><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-1-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-1-input" tabindex="0" value="8252"><span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label></mat-radio-button>
                <!----><!---->
             </span>
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TESTVESSELTECHM1</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-10-05</span><!---->
          </td>
          <!---->
       </tr>
       <tr _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted">
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted">
             <span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                <!---->
                <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-epp-c110="" color="primary" class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted mat-radio-checked" id="mat-radio-2"><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-2-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-2-input" tabindex="0" value="8253"><span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label></mat-radio-button>
                <!----><!---->
             </span>
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TESTVESSELTECHM2</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00122</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-10-15</span><!---->
          </td>
          <!---->
       </tr>
       <tr _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted">
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted">
             <span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                <!---->
                <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-epp-c110="" color="primary" class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" id="mat-radio-3"><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-3-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-3-input" tabindex="0" value="8301"><span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label></mat-radio-button>
                <!----><!---->
             </span>
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TESTVESSELTECHM1</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span><!---->
          </td>
          <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted">
             <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-10-25</span><!---->
          </td>
          <!---->
       </tr>
       <!----><!---->
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Hi your html of the table is not coorect , could you add the full table element]

Comment: @PDHide - Have added the entire table html but is not showing fully

Comment: please make sure to use diffwerent formatters when creating question , use code formatter to show code and html tags

Comment: @PDHide - got ok any inputs on this

Comment: the locator is not available in the html you provided

Comment: :mat-radio-button where is this >

Comment: @PDHide - 5th line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129839/discussion-between-jay-m-and-pdhide).

Comment: I've cleaned up the code format a little - that may help

Answer (score 0):

use xpath to select the entire row , and select individual td item using index

```
//tr[@role="row"][2]/td[3]
```

so for selecting radio button of first

```
//tr[@role="row"]/td[1]
```

to get text :

```
//tr[@role="row"]/td[1]
```

Comment: -I have already selected the radio button over here my only question is i need to get the text of the selected Radio button and the  radio button in this case will be randomly selected i could be either first or second etc so in this case as seen above after entering the loop what i need to do in order to get the text that is my question - @PDHide

Comment: @PDHide- thank you

Comment: You should navigate to parent element , but it's like going around the field. Instead select the row you want and then select radio , text etc from that row

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code `[Selenium + Java]` with the given HTML and it worked for me:

```
String rowOne = "";
String radioButton = "";
            
List<WebElement> radiobuttonoptions =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-radio-button[contains(@id,'mat-radio')]"));
for (WebElement radiobuttonoption : radiobuttonoptions)
{
    radioButton = radiobuttonoption.getAttribute("id");
    radioButton = "//mat-radio-button[contains(@id,'" + radioButton + "')]";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(radioButton)).click();
    rowOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath(radioButton + "//ancestor::tr/td[2]/span")).getText();
        System.out.println("Selected button is: "+ radioButton);
        System.out.println("Print the Selected VesselName:"+ rowOne);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

This is the HTML I used:

```
<html>

<body>
   <table class="mat-table cdk-table">
      <tbody role="rowgroup">
         <tr _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted">
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted">
               <span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-epp-c110="" color="primary"
                     class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" id="mat-radio-1"><label
                        class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-1-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span
                              class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input
                              type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-1-input"
                              tabindex="0" value="8252"><span mat-ripple=""
                              class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span
                                 class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span
                           class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
                  </mat-radio-button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
               </span>
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TESTVESSELTECHM1</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-10-05</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <!---->
         </tr>
         <tr _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted">
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted">
               <span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-epp-c110="" color="primary"
                     class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted mat-radio-checked" id="mat-radio-2"><label
                        class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-2-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span
                              class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input
                              type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-2-input"
                              tabindex="0" value="8253"><span mat-ripple=""
                              class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span
                                 class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span
                           class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
                  </mat-radio-button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
               </span>
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TESTVESSELTECHM2</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00122</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-10-15</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <!---->
         </tr>
         <tr _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted">
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted">
               <span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-epp-c110="" color="primary"
                     class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" id="mat-radio-3"><label
                        class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-3-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span
                              class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input
                              type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-3-input"
                              tabindex="0" value="8301"><span mat-ripple=""
                              class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span
                                 class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span
                           class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
                  </mat-radio-button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
               </span>
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TESTVESSELTECHM1</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <td _ngcontent-epp-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell=""
               class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><span _ngcontent-epp-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-10-25</span>
               <!---->
            </td>
            <!---->
         </tr>
         <!---->
         <!---->
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>

</html>
```